# How to register 'Arnold' render

Tags: python, maya

I followed the http://www.toadstorm.com/blog/?p=136 to open a maya scene without the UI.

This is the main script:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import subprocess
# replace mayaPath with the path on your system to mayapy.exe
mayaPath = 'C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/mayapy.exe'
# replace scriptPath with the path to the script you just saved
scriptPath = 'C:/Users/Rik/Desktop/CreateNewLayerWithMeshesForBatchRenderPurpose.py'
def massAddRenderLayer(filenames, layername):
    for filename in filenames:
        maya = subprocess.Popen(mayaPath+' '+scriptPath+' '+filename+' '+layername,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out,err = maya.communicate()
        exitcode = maya.returncode
        if str(exitcode) != '0':
            print(err)
            print 'error opening file: %s' % (filename)
        else:
            print 'added new layer %s to %s' % (out,filename)


filenames = ['C:\Users\Rik\Desktop\Test_maya_file_FILE1.ma'] 
renderLayerToAdd = 'newRenderLayer'

massAddRenderLayer(filenames, renderLayerToAdd)
```

and this is the script that is called for:

```
import sys
import maya.standalone as std
std.initialize(name='python')
import maya.cmds as cmds
from mtoa.cmds.arnoldRender import arnoldRender
filename = sys.argv[1]
layername = sys.argv[2]

def addRenderLayer(filename,layername):
    try:
        cmds.file(filename,o=True,f=True)
        newLyr = cmds.createRenderLayer(n=layername,empty=True,makeCurrent=True)
        meshes = cmds.ls(type='mesh')
        xforms = []
        for i in meshes:
            xf = cmds.listRelatives(i,p=True)[0]
            xforms.append(xf)
            cmds.editRenderLayerMembers(layername,xforms)

        cmds.loadPlugin( 'mtoa.mll' )
        arnoldRender(1, 1, True, True,'camera1', ' -layer' + newLyr)
        cmds.setAttr("defaultArnoldDriver.ai_translator", "png", type="string")
        cmds.setAttr("defaultArnoldDriver.pre", "file_name", type="string")
        arnoldRender(1920, 1080, True, True,'camera1', ' -layer' + newLyr)

        sys.stdout.write(newLyr)
        return newLyr
    except Exception, e:
        sys.stderr.write(str(e))
        sys.exit(-1)

addRenderLayer(filename,layername)
```

When I run the main script he opens the mayapy.exe program, but when I want to render a frame then I get an error saying `Failed to register renderer 'arnold'` even when I have imported arnold and loaded the 'mtoa.mll' plugin.
How can I 'register 'arnold''?

Comment: Debugging questions (1) does your install work with Arnold in GUI mode? (2) have you tried doing the same tasks interactively with Mayapy.exe from the command line?

Comment: @theodox, (1)The script works when I run it in GUI mode. After that I copied and pasted it over to this script. (2) I think that I did that, but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: If you run mayapy from the command line as a REPL, can you then import the addRenderLayer script?

Comment: @theodox, when I try to import the addRenderLayer script via the command line, I get the error: `Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 1: name 'CreateNewLayerWithMeshesForBatchRenderPurpose' is not defined # `. 'CreateNewLayerWithMeshesForBatchRenderPurpose' is the script that is called for. Though when I `import pymel.core as pm`, the original error doesn't show up.

Comment: If you add C:/Users/Rik/Desktop' to your path or pythonpath in  the REPL, and then import CreateNewLayerWithMeshesForBatchRenderPurpose, does it work?
Or you could move the script into your maya scripts folder to make it easier for Mayapy to find -- it uses the same search paths as GUI maya

Comment: @theodox, I tried it again with the filePath as you suggested. When I run the line `execfile("C:/Users\Rik/Desktop/CreateNewLayerWithMeshesForBatchRenderPurpose.py")` in mayapy, there were some problems with the 'addRenderLayer' function so I rewrote the script without the function. This is the result:`import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize ()
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm
from mtoa.cmds.arnoldRender import arnoldRender
cmds.loadPlugin( 'mtoa.mll' )`

Comment: `cmds.file('C:\Users\Rik\Desktop\Test_maya_file_FILE1.ma',open =True,f=True)

arnoldRender(1, 1, True, True,'camera1', ' -layer defaultRenderLayer')
cmds.setAttr("defaultArnoldDriver.ai_translator", "jpeg", type="string")
cmds.setAttr("defaultArnoldDriver.pre", "FILE_1_RENDER", type="string")
arnoldRender(1920, 1080, True, True,'camera1', ' -layer defaultRenderLayer')` , But now I don't know how to pass the maya filePath from 1 script to other. Or can I merge both scripts?

Comment: I'd try combining them for now, just to work around the render issue.